# Can someone explain why this query sometimes brings back zero rows other times multiple rows when I am only ever expecting 1 record

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, mariadb, myisam

I am trying to a get a single random row back from a table and to do this I am can using `FLOOR(1 + rand() * 50)` to get a valid row ID. *50 equals the amount of records in my table (I actually have a couple of thousand but as an example I'm keeping this small).*

The SQL ends up being this

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
SELECT id FROM ids WHERE id = FLOOR(1 + rand() * 50)
```

But when I run this query either returns

- 0 records
- 1 record
- 2+ records

The issue is that I always need 1 record back; I could put a LIMIT on there but sometimes I even don't get a record back plus I shouldn't need to as FLOOR(1 + rand() * 50) will always return a valid row ID.

I know there are other ways I can do this but now I just need to understand why this is happening. To demonstrate here is my example table

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
CREATE TABLE `ids` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I then run the following 50 times

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
INSERT INTO `ids` (`id`) VALUES (NULL);
```

So now my table looks like this (but with another 48 records underneath)

```
id |
---|
1  |
2  |
.
.
```

With the table of IDs set up I proceed to keep running the first query, remembering that `FLOOR(1 + rand() * 50)` always returns a valid ID within range and I get

```
id |
---|
25 |
30 |
43 |
```

or

```
id |
---|
```

or

```
id |
---|
41 |
```

Declaring the ID you are going to look up does actually get around this problem.

```
SET @randomID = FLOOR(1 + rand() * 50); 
SELECT id FROM ids WHERE id = @randomID;
```

Though I am still not understanding why I get more than 1 record back in the original query.

Comment: My guess is that `rand()` is inovoked for every row in table, which means for every row in your table `FLOOR(1 + rand() * 50)` is different, and every time there is a chance that id of current row is equal to this expression. In second example `rand()` is inovoked only once. Otherwise `order by rand()` wouldn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard docs says -

*RAND() in a WHERE clause is evaluated for every row (when selecting from one table)*

If you don't want to declare a variable -

```
select id from `ids`
join (select FLOOR(1 + rand() * 50) as id) b using(id);
```

[DOC LINK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)

Comment: Is shot, RTFM ;) Thanks for that and an example too.